# Asynchronous anonymous function in Kotlin? (lambda expressions)

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, lambda

I'm making a listview (android) what call function when click.

and `I want to get function is async or sync`.

to block when it is async.

and even i want to know `how attach async mark to kotlin lambda expression`.

```
class FunctionCaller_Content(text: List<String>,
                             val function: List<    /*suspend? @async? */
                                                    (    () -> Unit    )?
                                               >? = null)
                                                 /* I want both of async, sync function. */
{

    fun isAsnyc(order: Int): Boolean
        = // how to get this lambda expression{function?.get(order)} is async?

    fun call(callerActivity: Activity, order: Int) {
        val fun = function?.get(order)
        fun()
        if(isAsync(fun))
            /* block click for async func */
    }

}
```

and usage.

```
FunctionCaller_Content( listOf("Click to Toast1", "Click to Nothing"),
                        listOf(
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        },
                        {
                            /*if async lambda expression, how can i do?*/
                        } )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have `List<suspend () -> Unit>`, but you can't have both suspend and non-suspend functions in the same list except by using `List<Any>`. I'd suggest using two separate lists instead. Another solution is to use "algebraic data type":

```
sealed class SyncOrAsync // can add methods here
class Sync(val f: () -> Unit) : SyncOrAsync
class Async(val f: suspend () -> Unit) : SyncOrAsync

class FunctionCaller_Content(text: List<String>,
                             val function: List<SyncOrAsync>? = null)
{

    fun call(callerActivity: Activity, order: Int) {
        val fun = function?.get(order)
        if(fun is Async)
            /* block click for async func */
    }

}

FunctionCaller_Content( 
    listOf("Click to Toast1", "Click to Nothing"),
    listOf(Sync {
               Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           },
           Async {
               // your async code
           })
```

But if you are just going to block anyway, I would just use `List<() -> Unit>` and

```
listOf({
           Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       },
       {
           runBlocking {
               // your async code
           }
       })
```

Comment: Thank you. you help me a lot. but it is on UI thread. so I must try to block only click. and how get ```isAsync()``` ```if I use List<Any>``` ?...??? impossible?? I try to ```if(func is (suspend()->Unit)```, it doesn't work....

Comment: and this code doesn't work. T_T... because run{} is inline so it return not ```()->Unit```.

Comment: Fixed the code (you can extract `{ runBlocking { ... } }` into a function to simplify).